# Programatically change the Fn key behavoiur Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to write a simple cmdline app that will toggle the "Use all F1,F2... keys as standard function keys". I know i can use appleScript, but that shows the gui and is not nice. So how to do that from code? I tried the defaults command `defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState -bool false` and that does change the preferences flag when read with defaults command but not in the GUI and it is not working. 
Also tried something like that:

```
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSString *key = @"com.apple.keyboard.fnState";
    BOOL fnState =  [defaults boolForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"First value of fnState: %@", fnState ? @"true" : @"false" );
    if (fnState) {
        [defaults setBool:NO forKey:key];
    }
    else{
        [defaults setBool:YES forKey:key];
    }
    fnState =  [defaults boolForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"Value of fnState after toggle: %@", fnState ? @"true" : @"false" );
    [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
```

This one has proper states logged between runs, but defaults command does not see it, and the Fn key does not care either.

How should one proceed ? I know it can be done.

Comment: Google "os x change function keys command line" finds a bunch of suggestions, but it looks like they mostly involve AppleScripting the system preferences. I suspect the API to remap the keys is privileged.

Comment: If all else fails you could use NSTask to wrap defaults write

Comment: Have you tried CFPreferences? https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFPreferencesUtils/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFPreferencesSetValue

Comment: @uchuugaka NSTask wrapping makes not much sense in given example, as i cannot get even defaults command to work and change the Fn key function. It just flips things in the plist.

Comment: @Barmar API most definitely is public. There is an app in Mac app store (sandboxed even?) that does that.

Comment: It makes plenty of sense if you read how plists and preferences are cached in memory and that's not one owned by your app. If edit that plist and log out or restart you might just see a change.

Comment: @uchuugaka i appreciate your input, but login/logout is out of question. It needs to be less hassle than flipping it in preferences from the user perspective.

Comment: No doubt a hassle. Just letting you know that editing a plist or defaults write does not necessarily have a live effect.